How to adjust alignment of `MapCameraPosition ` in iOS 17
Using Xcode 15.4. I want to position and follow the user's location on a Map, but I want to position the camera "above" the user's location (or align the user's location to the bottom of the screen). My view currently looks like this:
struct MapView: View {
    @State var position: MapCameraPosition = .userLocation(
        followsHeading: true,
        fallback: .automatic
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(position: $position) {
            UserAnnotation()
        }
    }
}

This gives the following look:

However, I'd like something like this:


I could manually calculate an offset from the user's location but it doesn't take care of what happens when the user starts facing a different direction. Any help would be appreciated

"but it doesn't take care of what happens when the user starts facing a different direction" You can probably calculate that using some geometry too. This is otherwise not supported.
